# android sqlite concurrent saving

Tags: java, android, sqlite, concurrency

For an application I am writing I currently have a problem with concurrent saving to an sqlite database.

The situation is as followed:

I have a listview, when it is clicked, that item is marked for synchronization. A flag is saved to the database. Also, an async thread is then started which retrieves data from a server and then saves it locally to the sqlite database.

During this time, other list item's can be clicked, which would mark them for synchronization(and write a flag that it requires a sync to the database)

The flag is needed incase the user leaves the app or the app is killed, a project is marked for synchronization but not yet synchronized.

The code that is called from the ui thread:
[executed from UI thread]

```
Project p = (Project) obj;
if (p.getDoSync() == 0){
   p.setDoSync(1);
   p.save();
}
```

this code can be executed at the same time as the following code, which is residing in an async method:

[executed from async method]

```
 for (Project project : ProjectRepository.forSyncStatus(SyncStatus.NEEDS_SYNC)){
    try {
       db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
       project.sync();
       db.setTransactionSuccessful();
       } finally {
          db.endTransaction();
       }
    }
```

We are working with alot of json data with nested objects.
project.sync() undresses the json and creates java objects out of them and saves them. 
So a project.sync(); itself contains multiple inserts.

The problem is not the app crashing, but the UI freezing. 
How can I prevent the UI from freezing? I am at a complete loss right now.

[EDIT] I have experimented a bit. The problem is the transaction. 
The transaction however is nescesary because otherwise project.sync(); will take ages. 
Without the transaction there is no UI freeze.

Comment: Are you sure you are performing network operations not on the Main Thread (UI Thread)?

Comment: @silverback The first code snipped that includes p.setDoSync(1); and p.save(); is done from the UI thread. Hence the UI freezes. But the save should take a few ms at most. But it is waiting for the second snippet to finish before commiting its save. That is causing the freeze. As of yet, I have no clue of a solution.

Comment: Hello, Is the second snippet run as a separate background thread?

Comment: @silverback I editted my answer. The first snipped is UI thread, the second snippet is from an ASYNC method. Also on the bottom of my post I wrote a small [edit] section, i hope it might help to lead to an answer.

Comment: Ok. If my understanding is correct, if your transaction is in asynchronous, that shouldn't cause a UI Freeze.

Comment: @silverback No but the code from the ui thread is called while a transaction from another thread is in process. This causes the code from the UI to wait untill the transaction is ended, and then saves and resumes the ui. But the transaction is nescesary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27394/discussion-between-silverback-and-joey-roosing)